# how to seperate MySQL LOAD DATA on lines that start WITHOUT an extra space?

Tags: mysql, file

I have an input file filled with data that I want to upload into a MySQL table using a MySQL stored procedure.

Right now, the data looks like this:
[New lines start at lines that do not have an extra space before them.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiYrz.png)

I want to fill this data in 15 columns, how can I seperate the lines that have no extra space before them, while keeping the lines that do have an empty space?

My code so far:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/example_data.txt' INTO TABLE testProc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  '
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n '
(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12, field13, field14, field15);
```

Comment: MySQL is a database, not a universal tool for whatever crap someone produces. Use something else to have an easy to read CSV file.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding. The problem lies here that this is a txt file, not CSV. This has also specifically been a requirement to make from the database. Is there anything else I can do to make this work?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a txt or csv or asdf as long as there are simple ascii characters in it. Like I said, use another tool to format the file. If you would use Linux I could help you with tools like sed, on Windows I have no clue what you could use. Good luck.